# Python countdown not line by line

Tags: python, printing

so i tried to create a countdown in python. It works fine, but I want to have a better print output. At the moment it prints the remaining time line by line, so my output is overfilled after some time. I then tried to do:

```
import time

def countdown(t):
    while t:

        print(t, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    print('finished')

countdown(60)
```

but it outputs for me:

```
5
4
3
2
1
finished
```

I'd like to have it that it prints the countdown and the finished all in one line and deletes the number before it...
Thanks for helping :)
Here's what it should look like:
But i dont need the 00:00 format, the seconds are fine for me
[image]

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Might be a Windows problem.  Windows doesn't handle newlines the way Unix does.

Comment: If you are running in an idle it will depend on the exact system. If you're using a shell or command prompt then the following will work. `sys.stdout.write("{}\b".format(t))` "Tested in windows CMD.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter, it should work in windows cmd. Your ```sys.stdout.write("{}\b".format(t))``` outputs the following: ```54321finished``` but i'd like to have it like you can see in the gif.

Comment: You just need multiple "\b" depending on the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

almost there, below code will print your timer value side by side. not sure what  'deletes the number before it.' is!

```
import time

def countdown(t):
    while t:

        print(t, end=" ")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    print('finished')

countdown(60)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to print the code in the same line and delete the number which was before it, so i dont completly spam the output of my script with numbers

Answer (score 0):

Delete the previous character using '\b'

```
import time

def countdown(t):
    # how many digits
    digits = int(t / 10) + 1
    while t:
        print('\b{}'.format(str(t).zfill(digits)), end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    print('finished')

countdown(10)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this outputs:
```
5
4
3
2
1
finished
```, line by line

Comment: Are you sure you are running the right script? Here is a repl of the above script https://repl.it/@PanayiotisPanay/KindlyDarksalmonLoopfission

Comment: Sorry, i tried to run it on idle and pycharm and it didnt work. It works in cmd

Comment: The pycharm console doesn't treat '\b' correctly, this is a known pycharm bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11300

Comment: 1) That is not how you calculate the number of digits in a number (try your code with countdown(100) for proof). 2) If you're using end="\r" then the backspace ("\b") is unnecessary,

Comment: 1. int(100/10) + 1 = 3 which is the number of digits of 100. Tried countdown(100), works just fine. 2) the point of the backspace is to not change lines every time (which is what the question asks). Without backspace, it prints a separate line for each number.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work if called from `Windows CMD`

```
import time, sys, os

def pretty_format(seconds):
    seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600)
    hour = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    # Here's the formatting you asked for!  00:00:59 etc...
    return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hour, minutes, seconds)  

def count_down(seconds):
    os.system("cls")  # Windows -> clear the cmd screen


    while seconds:
        sys.stdout.write("{}{}".format(pretty_format(seconds), "\b"*100)) # \b replaces the previous value. if we have a bunch of values we need to do multiple \b. Here's 100!
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds -=1
    print('finished')

count_down(60)
```